# Calling a function only once state and any related effects have finished updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a buttonClick that essentially does the following:

```
function func() {
      const [bool, setBool] = useState();
      const [data, setData] = useState({});
      
      useEffect(()=>{
        if(bool) {
          setData({bool: true})
        } else {
          setData({bool: false})          
        }
      }, [bool]);
     
      onClick=(evt)=>{
         setBool(true);
         sendToDb(data);
      }
}
```

I understand that useState is async. Is there a way in react that I can have the call to send to the db wait until until the useEffect that will set the data has completed?

Answer (score 0):

Just use another useEffect to send your data.

```
function func() {
      const [bool, setBool] = useState();
      const [data, setData] = useState({});
      
      useEffect(()=>{
        if(bool) {
          setData({bool: true})
        } else {
          setData({bool: false})          
        }
      }, [bool]);

      useEffect(()=>{
        sendToDb(data);
      }, [data]);
     
      onClick=(evt)=>{
         setBool(true);
      }
}
```

Comment: I would rather not do it like this. Just because data is changed, doesn't mean that I want to send it to the database. its specifically only when the button is clicked, and that setBool changes the data, and then it sends

Comment: Then you can either use a condition before calling sendToDb or create another state and change it only when setBool changes the data, then based on that state variable you call sendToDb like we did on data change